# What is the solution of given equation?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Is the solution correct for the given equation?

$\log (x) + \frac {2\cdot u}{x}=0$

On differentiation,
$\frac 1x  - \frac {2\cdot u}{x^2}=0$

$x=2\cdot u$

Comment: No, you are locating the extremum of the LHS, not its root.

Answer (score 1):

This is a transcendental equation that has no analytical solution. Anyway, you can gain some insight by considering

$$u=-\frac{x\log x}2.$$

This function is initially positive, reaches the maximum $(1/e,e/2)$, then crosses the axis at $(1,0)$ and decreases monotonically.

So the number of roots is

$$\begin{cases}
  u < 0 &\to 1,&x>1\\
  u = 0 &\to 2,&x=0\text{ and }x=1\\
  0 < u < 1/e &\to 2,&0<x<1/e\text{ and } 1/e<x<1\\
  u= 1/e &\to 1\text{ (double)},&x=e/2\\
  u > 1/e &\to 0.
\end{cases}$$